# Define constants in Perl with variable name

Tags: perl, constants

I would like to create perl-constants from a configuration file. I'm using Config::File to read a config file that looks like this:

```
ABC = DEF
GHI = JKL
```

With Config::File that creates a hashref which looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'ABC' => 'DEF',
    'GHI' => 'JKL'
};
```

I would like to use that hashref to create constants where the name of the constant should be the key and the value should be the corresponding value from the hashref. Manually I would do something like

```
use constant ABC => 'DEF';
use constant GHI => 'JKL';
```

I tried doing something this:

```
foreach my $const (keys %$hashref) {
    use constant $const => $keys->{$const};
}
```

but as expected that doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `use constants` is a pragma that gets called at compile time. Your variables are only there at run time. You cannot do that outside of a `BEGIN` block or in an eval. I'll write an answer in a bit with alternatives and explanation.

Comment: I have to say, I've never really seen much value in 'use constant' in perl. It seems to be a bit more brittle than ... well, just 'not'.

Comment: @Sobrique: In my case it's used to store login credentials for external APIs. It's the easiest way to make them accessible to the scripts that need them. What's the alternative you would use?

Comment: I'd just use a hash, and not constantify them.

Comment: I'm not sure how true this is, but I think, that using constants is way faster than accessing a hash every time I need to use a credential. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: I echo @Sobrique's suggestion of using a hash. Using constants over a hash sounds like a micro-optimization

Comment: That's a whole other debate, but I think if there's an easy way to use constants over a hash, it's worth it, if it can shave off a couple of milliseconds, considering the application I'm working on is pretty huge and used by a lot of people.

Comment: If performance is a concern, then ... I still wouldn't do this. But write your code the 'easy/obvious' way, then profile it to see where the hotspots are. I'd be pretty confident that that amount of time you save isn't particularly significant.

Comment: The amount of time to fetch a hash key is *minuscule* compared to the time it takes to read your config file from disk. If you want to speed up your program, optimize something that's actually a bottleneck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer, to pick up from the comments - hashes vs. constants:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

use constant ABC => 'DEF';
use constant GHI => 'JKL';

my $ABC = 'DEF';
my $GHI = 'JKL';

my %test_hash = (
   ABC => 'DEF',
   GHI => 'JKL'
);

sub access_hash {
   my $value  = $test_hash{ABC};
   my $value2 = $test_hash{DEF};
}

sub access_constant {
   my $value  = ABC;
   my $value2 = GHI;
}

sub access_scalar { 
    my $value = $ABC;
    my $value2 = $GHI;
} 

my $count = 100_000_000;

cmpthese(
   $count,
   {  'hash'     => \&access_hash,
      'constant' => \&access_constant,
      'scalar'   => \&access_scalar
   }
);
```

Results:

```
               Rate     hash   scalar constant
hash      9427736/s       --      -7%     -10%
scalar   10143017/s       8%       --      -3%
constant 10492078/s      11%       3%       --
```

So you're right - it's faster to use a constant. However, I'd suggest for an operation that runs at a rate of 10M/sec, 'saving' 5% (or even 10%) is simply not worth the hackery you'll need to do it.

But in the interests of actually answering the question - the root of this problem is that `constant` is defined at compile time, where variables ... aren't.

There's simply no hash existing when the `constant` is defined, so that isn't going to work. You're also quite limited in what you can actually do in a `BEGIN` block. My thought would be that you could *probably* run a 'compile' process to turn your config file into a `.pm` that you could then `use`.

```
package import_const;

use constant ABC => 'DEF';
use constant GHI => 'JKL';
```

Then `use import_const;` and access your constants as `import_const::ABC`. (Or use `Exporter` to bring them into the local namespace).

```
sub from_pkg { 
    my $value  = import_const::ABC;
    my $value2 = import_const::GHI;
}
```

Add that into the timing test:

```
                        Rate        hash     scalar imported constant   constant
hash               9497578/s          --        -6%               -9%        -9%
scalar            10063399/s          6%         --               -4%        -4%
imported constant 10473398/s         10%         4%                --        -0%
constant          10492078/s         10%         4%                0%         --
```

I think I'd still argue that the gains are marginal for the effort. Especially given [use constant will surprise you with it's evil](https://earino.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/use-constant-will-surprise-you-with-its-evil/)

There may be a module that can do what you need though:

[CPAN modules for defining constants](http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html)

Comment: Using the configuration file as code and embedding it into the configuration module would work, but that's not a good way to do that, since inducing code from an external source is not a good practice. Thanks for the answer, though, I'll have to look at other ways to implement what I need!

Comment: ... yes, but introducing code from another source is what you're trying to do, by 'compiling' constants off a dynamic input.

Comment: Anyway, you may find [Review of 'constant' options'](http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html) to be useful.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you can do

```
use constant {
   CONST1 => VAL1,
   CONST2 => VAL2,
   ...
};
```

---

```
use constant LIST
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
   require constant;
   constant->import(LIST);
}
```

or

```
use constant qw( );
BEGIN {
   constant->import(LIST);
}
```

so you can do

```
use constant qw( );
use FindBin  qw( $RealBin );
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

BEGIN {
   my $qfn = "$RealBin/constants.json";
   open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn) or die $!;
   my $file; { local $/; $file = <$fh>; }
   my $constants = decode_json($file);  # { 'ABC' => 'DEF', 'GHI' => 'JKL' };
   constant->import($constants);
}
```

---

A cleaner solution might be to use a mini module.

```
package MyConstantsFromFile;

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant qw( );
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

sub import {
   my $class = shift;
   my $qfn = shift;
   open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn) or die $!;
   my $file; { local $/; $file = <$fh>; }
   my $constants = decode_json($file);  # { 'ABC' => 'DEF', 'GHI' => 'JKL' };
   my $import = constant->can('import');
   @_ = ('constant', $constants);
   goto &$import;
}

1;
```

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use MyConstantsFromFile "$RealBin/constants.json";
```